# How to receive a touch ended event if a finger is already touching the screen when the app loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch

I need to track if the user is touching the screen across multiple views and separate screens throughout my app. I have already created a window delegate method to receive every type of touch event. The problem is that if I keep one finger on the first screen and tap a button with a separate finger that takes me to the second screen, when I release my original finger no event is fired.

This problem is the same if you were to hold your finger on the screen before the app loads and then release it once it's started, no event is fired for the touch ending.

I presume there is some in built system in iOS that states you have to start a new touch once the app has started or the screen/view has changed, so if you release a finger that was already touching nothing happens.

Is there a way to detect this? I really need to keep a constant accurate number of touches on the screen throughout the different screens/views within my app, especially if the user takes their finger(s) off the screen.